# closed intervals and limit of a sequence

Tags: general-topology

Closed intervals are gotten by " Closing up" intervals so that sequences must limit to points in the intervals itself.

> Does this notion generalize?
> How are closed sets related to limits of sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a subset of $ \mathbb R^n$ (or more general a subset of a metric space).

Then we have:

$A$ is closed $ \iff$ for each convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ it holds that $ \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n \in A.$